# Is $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} (1+Ct)^{p} t^{q} dt$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Fix $C>0$ and $q, p>0.$

> Can we find the upper  bound of  the following integral:
>   $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} (1+Ct)^{p} t^{q} dt?$$
>   If so, how that upper bound will depend on $C$?

Comment: Convergence is easy: $e^{-t/2} t^{n}$ is bounded for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you mean integrable, don't you?

Comment: @lcv I did mean bounded. Notice that I have written $e^{-t/2}$, not $e^{-t}$. This boundedness together with integrability of $e^{-t/2}$ will yield convergnce of the given integral.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, it's a little convoluted way to put it, but nice.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned it is clearly convergent and also has a closed form expression. However, if you are looking for a simpler upper bound, then you can do something like this. Note that if $p \in (0,1)$ then $(1 + Ct)^p \leq 1 + (Ct)^p$ and if $p \geq 1$ then $(1 + Ct)^p \leq p(1 + (Ct)^p)$. Thus, we can combine both of them to write $(1 + Ct)^p \leq \max \{ 1, p\}(1 + (Ct)^p)$. Using this, we can write,
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t} (1 + Ct)^p t^q & \leq \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t} \max \{ 1, p\}(1 + (Ct)^p) t^q \\
& \leq  \max \{ 1, p\} \left( \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^q +  C^p \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t} t^{p+q}  \right) \\
& \leq  \max \{ 1, p\} \left( \Gamma(q+1) +  C^p \Gamma(p + q + 1)  \right) \\
\end{align}

This also gives you the required dependence on $C$ which is $O(C^p)$ as one would intuitively expect.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for the fun of it.*

A CAS produces the "nice" expression
$$I=\pi  \csc (\pi  (p+q)) \left(\frac{q \, \Gamma (q) \,
   _1\tilde{F}_1\left(q+1;p+q+2;\frac{1}{c}\right)}{c^{q+1}\Gamma (-p)}-c^p \,
   _1\tilde{F}_1\left(-p;-p-q;\frac{1}{c}\right)\right)$$  where appears the regularized confluent hypergeometric function under the condtions $(\Re(c)\geq 0\lor c\notin \mathbb{R})\land \Re(q)>-1$

Enjoy it !

Comment: @CL: Thanks. Please would you let me know: what is $\tilde{F_1}$. Any references?

Comment: @Learn. Have a look at  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html and have fun ! Cheers :-)